# Is there a way to make an enum return a UIViewController

Tags: ios, swift

Is there a way to make an enum return a UIViewController, not just strings or ints?

```
enum MyEnum {
    case movie
    case music
    case notes

    var viewController: UIViewController {
        case .movie: return MovieViewController
        case .music: return MusicViewController
        case .notes: return NotesViewController
    }
}
```

Comment: When i do that I get "Cannot convert return expression of type 'MovieViewController' to return type 'UIViewController'"

Comment: Do MovieViewController, MusicViewController and NotesViewController inherit from `UIViewController`?

Comment: @久美子 `MovieViewController` etc. should be inherited from `UIViewController`

Comment: @RomanRyzhiy yes they are inherited from `UIViewController`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do this:

```
enum MyEnum {
case movie
case music
case notes

var viewController: UIViewController {
    
    switch self {
  
    case .movie: return MovieViewController()
    case .music: return MusicViewController()
    case .notes: return NotesViewController()
    default: break
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: That obviously assumes OP is not using storyboards.

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure MovieViewController is inherited from UIViewController
2. Make sure you import UIKit in your enum class file

**Note:** You should not have UIKit components in your models.

Answer (score 0):

```
 enum Storyboard : String {
    case main               = "Main"

/// This function returns controller instance of specified storyboard. Please set same name for storyboard identifier otherwise application will crash.
/// - Parameter name: Controller Name
func controller<T : UIViewController>(_ name : T.Type) -> T {
    let controller = UIStoryboard.init(name: self.rawValue, bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "\(name)")
    return controller as! T
  }
}
 //Call it like this where you need this
let controller = Storyboard.home.controller(LoginViewController.self)
```

While using storyboard and generics you can also create enum like this and get your desired controller from your desired storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

```
enum MyEnum {
    case movie
    case music
    case notes

    var viewControllerType: UIViewController.Type {
        case .movie: return MovieViewController.self
        case .music: return MusicViewController.self
        case .notes: return NotesViewController.self
    }
}
```

I think this is what you're meaning for :D
Hope to help!!! :D

I had made some utils. Feel free to check it at https://github.com/haiphamthanh/Challenges/blob/other_tableview_layouts/DesignPatterns/AppStoryboard.swift